# Почему не кликает dispatchGesture

Tags: android, kotlin

Разрешение AccessibilityService вроде дал Выполняю функции в AccessibilityService Вот выполняются в AccessibilityService Причем если дебажить заметил выполняется dispatchGesture 2 раза и ни onCompleted ни onCancelled ни Exception не вызываются. Что может не так быть?

```
fun playStart(scenario: Scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario
        playClick()
    }

    fun playClick() {
        if(indexAction == null) {
            indexAction = 1
        }
        try {
           /* var clScenario: ScenarioClick = scenario!!.lstScenrioClick[indexAction!!]
            var widgLnk: IWigetCallback? = scenario!!.views[indexAction!!]
            var protect: Boolean = scenario!!.configClick.protect
            var interval = if(!protect) scenario!!.configClick.intervalClick else scenario!!.configClick.intervalClick //пока так
            var coordClick = getRealCoordClick(clScenario, widgLnk!!, protect)*/
            var path = Path()
//            path.moveTo(coordClick.x.toFloat(), coordClick.y.toFloat())
            path.moveTo(150f, 150f)
            val clickBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
            clickBuilder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(path, 10L, 100L))
            val gestureDescription: GestureDescription = clickBuilder.build()

            dispatchGesture(gestureDescription, object : GestureResultCallback() {
                override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription) {
                    super.onCompleted(gestureDescription)
                    /*indexAction = indexAction!! + 1
                    if(indexAction!! >= scenario!!.lstScenrioClick.size ) {
                        L.i("fffff")
                        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable!!, 2000)
                    } else {*/
                        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable!!, 2000)
                   // }
                }
                override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription) {
                    super.onCancelled(gestureDescription)
                }
            }, null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.i("exception = "+e.toString())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я имею схожую проблему.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949806/working-with-accessibilityservice-dispatchgesture-always-returns-false
У вас случайно не нашлось ответа на вопрос?